# Timeout trying to use Google BigQuery API

Tags: vb.net, google-bigquery

I'm trying to retrieve data using the Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 API:

```
Dim optns As New QueryOptions
optns.AllowLargeResults = True
projectId = PROJECTID1
datasetId = DATASETID1
parameters = Nothing      
client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId)
BQResults = client.ExecuteQuery(QUERY, parameters, optns)
```

Whenever the query gets more than 5 minutes to extract data it throws a timeout exception. How can I extend the timeout to allow it to run longer?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found so far is to add this after `bigqueryclient.create`.

```
client.Service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Time)
```

And for querys that take much time processing using a job instead of executing query with the following:

```
Dim optns As New QueryOptions
optns.AllowLargeResults = True
job = client.CreateQueryJob(QUERY, parameters, optns)
job.PollUntilCompleted().ThrowOnAnyError()
BQResults = job.GetQueryResults
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the same thing on c# console app, but the 5min limit doesn't change regardless of what approach I take.

Here's an example of my code:

```
    using (BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(ProjectID, credential))
{
   client.Service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
   var CurrTimeOutSetting = client.Service.HttpClient.Timeout.TotalSeconds;
}
```

The value of 'CurrTimeOutSetting' comes up correctly when I debug, but when I run the program it times out at 5mins